# Software Center missing apps?

Tags: software-center, configuration

I have recently made the switch from windows to Linux, and am still trying to learn my way around this beautiful OS. Because I am new, I have not been able to familiarize myself with the awesome terminal tool and therefore rely heavily on Ubuntu Software Center. I was reading a guide that suggested an app from the Center but when I searched for it, nothing came up. I've noticed more and more apps I look for are nonexistent. Is there something I did wrong configuring my system that would cause this problem?

Thanks in advance for your patience.

Comment: Could it be that those apps you are refering to a not compatible with your version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Could you list some apps suggested in the guide that you were not able to find in the software center?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have only main-repository enabled.
Open Dash (Windows key), type Preferences, open them, search for Software. On the first tab you can enable Ubuntu software (main repository, universe, multiverse). There are also other repositories, for example playdeb. Playdeb offers some good games, which are not included in the Ubuntu-repositories.

If you have all ubuntu repositories enabled, maybe it is just a spelling problem. Try to use the english name of the software, with and without capital letters at the beginning.

Comment: This was my issue, but i cant upvote it without 15 rep. Thanks