# Why doesn't Ubuntu Software return relevant results?

Tags: software-center

The expected behavior of Ubuntu Software should be to return relevant results matching keywords in the query to the description of the software listing.  OR return no results.

When I query something trivial like "Sticky Notes" (no quotes) I return completely irrelevant results.  Why? and can this be fixed by me the user?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Software Center missing apps?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/326238/software-center-missing-apps)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Not a duplicate, at least not of that other question.

Answer (score 1):

Your search string example means entries with "sticky" or "notes" in it, and probably "notes" is existent in most of the entries.

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect the query pictured in the screenshot. In Ubuntu Software I enter Sticky Notes without quotes.  I expect my query to be handled like the most popular software search applications  on the planet -- Google Play or Apple App Store. There if I type in Sticky Notes, I will receive applications that offer sticky notes.

Comment: @Zach_is_my_name: Sounds like you want to file a [wishlist bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+filebug).